# Почему клиент WCF службы не видит конструктор класса?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Есть класс помеченный атрибутами для сериализации, который переганяет данные между клиентом и службой. В результате возникло несколько проблем:

1. Клиент не видит конструктор данного класса.
2. Все свойста в классе только на чтение, на клиенте они стали доступны и для записи.
3. При попытке сериализовать данный класс вылетает `exception` (`InnerException` пустой ):

> There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter
>   http://tempuri.org/:registrationData.  Please see InnerException for
>   more details.

```
    [DataContract]
    class RegistrationData
    {
        public RegistrationData(string nickName, string email, string password)
        {
            Nickname = nickName;
            Email = email;
            Password = password;
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Nickname { get; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Email { get; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Password { get; }
    }
```

Comment: конструктор без параметров добавьте

Comment: @Monk, И что изменится?

Comment: Ваш же вопрос - Почему клиент WCF службы не видит конструктор класса?

Comment: @Monk, Попробовал, все равно не видит.

Comment: Хм, ну класс ещё public можно сделать

Comment: @Monk, Попробовал, ничего не изменилось.

Comment: исключение при сериализации - добавьте открытые сеттеры свойствам и конструктор без параметров. Либо пишите свой вариант сериализации

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF магии не делает. Он просто перегоняет сериализованный класс, по схеме описанный в wsdl. А это значит что объекты пересылки представляют из себя так называемый DTO (data transfer object) класс.
Что это означает?
Он сериализуемый в самом простом смысле:

1. Публичный тип.
2. Все поля доступны на Get Set.
3. Все типы полей так же являются сериализуемыми. (вот почему конструктор без параметров не помог в вашем случае)
4. Есть публичный конструктор без параметров.

Как понимаем, эта сущность как модель неупотребима. Потому что инкапсуляцию игнорирует и ООП. Всвязи с этим DTO объекты нигде, кроме как в builder-e, фабрике, autoMapper-е или конструкторе не используются. И я бы, на вашем месте, тоже разделил их области ответственности и применения.

Comment: А я надеялся на какую-то неизвестную мне WCF магию.  Хороший ответ. Спасибо!

Comment: Ее можно создать самому. :) Есть несколько вариантов, но лучше начать с более простых и масштабируемых решений.

Comment: было б интересно посмотреть на какой-то вариант :)

Comment: Не стоит пока :). Гибкость разработки убивает влет. Это, скажем так, переписывание некоторых механизмов wcf, позволяющие использовать более шустрые методы сериализации. Но база кода сильно растет, и он становится не автогененириуемым. Так что в вопросах транспорта я бы придерживался обычных абстрактных механизмов. А оптимизация — удел работы после MVP (min viable product).